# Access violation writing location when push_back() in a C++ vector?

Tags: c++, class, vector, stl

**Background Info**

I was editing a completely different part of my source when "Access violation writing location 0x00000008" was thrown. Object loading was been working before and the part I modified before the bugged compile was in a completely different class.

**More points**

- I kept receiving "corruption of the heap" errors when exiting my program, but I hadn't fixed it.
- The only edit I made to the source before I compiled the buggy version was that I added 2 new vectors to another public class which has nothing to do with object loading. Did it run out of memory or something?

**Minimalized "ObjectHandler.hpp"**

```
#include "Object.hpp"
#include "SFML/System.hpp"
#include "SFML/Network.hpp"

struct objtex
{
    sf::Int32 id;
    sf::Texture* tx;
};

class ObjectHandler
{
    private:
        std::vector< std::vector < std::vector< Object* > > > objects;
        std::vector<objtex> textures;

    public:
        void loadTextures();
};
```

**Minimalized "Object Handler.cpp"**

```
void ObjectHandler::loadTextures()
{
    bool stillLoading = true;
    sf::Int32 id = 0;
    while(stillLoading)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "rsc/Objects/" << id << ".png";

        sf::Image i;
        if(i.loadFromFile(ss.str()))
        {
            i.createMaskFromColor(sf::Color(255, 0, 255));

            objtex o;
            o.id = id;
            o.tx = new sf::Texture;
            o.tx->loadFromImage(i);
            std::cout << "OOO";
            textures.push_back(o);      //  <<< THE PROBLEM >>>
            std::cout << "PPP";

            id += 1;
        }

        else
        {
            stillLoading = false;
            std::cout << "exited";
        }
    }
}
```

**Compile results**

Whenever I call loadTextures() from my Main.cpp, it throws the error at textures.push_back() after going through the loop *for the second time*. It works the first time. [This is what my console outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH3J4.png).

And [these are all of the warnings that are thrown compile-time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb9ac.png) (none of which appeared before I had these problems).

```
1>c:\users\brady\dropbox\dwell project\project\client\client\gamegui.cpp(2156): warning C4789: destination of memory copy is too small
1>c:\users\brady\dropbox\dwell project\project\client\client\gamegui.cpp(1923): warning C4789: destination of memory copy is too small
1>c:\users\brady\dropbox\dwell project\project\client\client\gamegui.cpp(1924): warning C4789: destination of memory copy is too small
1>c:\users\brady\dropbox\dwell project\project\client\client\objecthandler.cpp(261): warning C4715: 'ObjectHandler::getTexture' : not all control paths return a value
1>c:\users\brady\dropbox\dwell project\project\client\client\networkmanager.cpp(41): warning C4789: destination of memory copy is too small
1>c:\users\brady\dropbox\dwell project\project\client\client\actionhandler.cpp(226): warning C4715: 'ActionHandler::getActionName' : not all control paths return a value
1>c:\users\brady\dropbox\dwell project\project\client\client\game.cpp(19): warning C4789: destination of memory copy is too small
1>c:\users\brady\dropbox\dwell project\project\client\client\menu.cpp(487): warning C4789: destination of memory copy is too small
1>c:\users\brady\dropbox\dwell project\project\client\client\menu.cpp(585): warning C4789: destination of memory copy is too small
1>c:\users\brady\dropbox\dwell project\project\client\client\gamegui.cpp(1858): warning C4789: destination of memory copy is too small
1>c:\users\brady\dropbox\dwell project\project\client\client\gamegui.cpp(1859): warning C4789: destination of memory copy is too small
1>c:\users\brady\dropbox\dwell project\project\client\client\gamegui.cpp(607): warning C4789: destination of memory copy is too small
1>c:\users\brady\dropbox\dwell project\project\client\client\gamegui.cpp(612): warning C4789: destination of memory copy is too small
1>c:\users\brady\dropbox\dwell project\project\client\client\gamegui.cpp(837): warning C4789: destination of memory copy is too small
1>c:\users\brady\dropbox\dwell project\project\client\client\gamegui.cpp(838): warning C4789: destination of memory copy is too small
1>c:\users\brady\dropbox\dwell project\project\client\client\gamegui.cpp(848): warning C4789: destination of memory copy is too small
1>c:\users\brady\dropbox\dwell project\project\client\client\gamegui.cpp(855): warning C4789: destination of memory copy is too small
1>c:\users\brady\dropbox\dwell project\project\client\client\game.cpp(632): warning C4789: destination of memory copy is too small
1>c:\users\brady\dropbox\dwell project\project\client\client\networkmanager.cpp(879): warning C4789: destination of memory copy is too small
```

All of these warnings take me to random places in the code-- none of which have to do with allocation of memory. All completely random. For example:

```
Game::Game()
{
    windowPos = gl::Win.getPosition();

    sprinting = false;
    hit = false;
    hasFocus = true;
    dead = false;
    isChiefStaff = false;
    drawGUI = true;           //  <<<  WARNING POINTS HERE  >>> 
}
```

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**

- [11:04 11/16/2013] I just ran it in debug mode and it pointed to the beginning of my Game class, not the ObjectHandler class. The Game class was the one I edited by adding 2 new vectors. Interesting. It still throws the same exception as well.

**UPDATE**

- [7:02 11/16/2013] I fixed it. I rebuilt the solution and set all my pointers to NULL after deletion. This fixed all the corruption that happened to the heap. Thanks to those who helped.

Comment: `objtex` carries a raw resource - a pointer to `sf::Texture`. It'll need a copy constructor and an assignment operator and a destructor. Search for The rule of three.

Comment: Somewhere in your program you are overwriting a heap allocated buffer.  This corrupts the heap.  `vector<>` will allocate memory on the heap with you add items.  So your issue is that you have heap corruption some where.  Heap corruption doesn't usually cause an crash when it happens, but the next time something access the heap.  Fix you heap corruption.

Comment: You should copy the compiler warnings as text to your question instead of posting a screen dump. Also can you label the code that are the lines that the warning is complaining about if it is here. If it is not can you edit your question and put the code here so we can understand what you are doing at these lines.

Comment: @drescherjm Okay, I just editted the OP with some more info.

Comment: @shf301 I'll try to find the heap corruption, but is that what's causing this error? I just realized the only edit I made before these problems started happening was that I added a few more public vectors to another class.

Comment: Can you just show one example (copy the source code lines around the warning location) where the destination of memory copy is too small. I believe you are doing something wrong in the same way for all your objects.. And this is causing the heap corruption.

Comment: @drescherjm Sure. I noticed a patern. All of them have to do with places where I set a variable to a value.

These are all different examples of places the warnings point to. ex. "ent::game.isNew = false;", "crateX = X;", "crateY = Y;"

Comment: @Jungle - if you are overwriting the bounds of a buffer you get what in C is called "undefined behavior".   Since the behavior is undefined your code could work correctly, crash immediately, crash sometime later, or cause demons to fly out of your nose.  You can't reason about your program if it has undefined behavior since you don't know what it will do.  So yes that is likely your problem.

Comment: @Jungle For me its still hard to understand the cause. I would edit your question to put the exact code that is causing one of these warnings. Make sure you put some context. I mean a few lines above and below the call so we can see what exactly is going on.

Comment: @drescherjm Just updated the OP again

Comment: @shf301 Ok, thank you. I'll look around stackoverflow about ways to debug heap corruptions and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Are you declaring your classes more than 1 time in different ways. I mean 1 header for what the users of your class will see a different header for the implementation?

Comment: Is drawGUI declared as a bool?

Comment: @drescherjm Ok, update! I just ran it in debug mode and it pointed to my Game class, which is the class I edited. It didn't give a specific spot besides the beginning of the initialization of the class. Interesting...

Comment: @drescherjm I'm declaring it once, and yes, drawGUI is declared as a bool

Comment: Its very strange that Visual Studio would complain about this line. I am for the moment out of guesses.

Comment: @drescherjm Do you think it has to do with that heap corruption error I was getting a while ago?

Comment: Does `this` point to a valid `ObjectHandler`?

Comment: Yes I believe these warnings (about copying memory to a buffer that is too small) could cause serious heap corruption. However I am at a loss on how setting a bool could generate this error. Are you sure you are matching the correct line number from the compiler warning to the code? I mean are you really showing line 19 of game.cpp?

Comment: @drescherjm Oddly, the warnings do not show when run in debug mode-- only release mode.

Comment: Are you mixing debug and release dlls in your application (although I do not see this causing a warning)?

Comment: I would also fix the "not all control paths return a value" warnings. These look like they can be very dangerous especially since I expect they are supposed to return pointers to objects.

Comment: @drescherjm No, I am not mixing the two. And those 2 functions with no return path return references.

Comment: In the case of the reference it still would be undefined behavior if the caller would try to access the reference.

Comment: @drescherjm I just reset all the files back before I had any problems and the issue still persists. The Release compiles and actually runs before I load objects (a part of the code I never changed) while the Debug doesn't even past the initialization of the Game class. I find it *really* odd that even after I reset all the files and everything, this problem still persists...

Comment: Could you write a short answer and accept it, so this doesn't show as unresolved?

Comment: @Lukas Done. Just posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. I rebuilt the solution and set all my pointers to NULL after deletion. This fixed all the corruption that happened to the heap. Thanks to those who helped.

Moral of the story:
Always fix corruption of the heap errors before they corrupt your builds!